# Error in WebSocket connection to ws://localhost:35729/ java application with azure integration

Tags: java, azure

I have developed a java application based on spring-boot and vaadin and I am planning to include a user management linked with azure.

The app runs in localhost:8080, and before starting it is necessary to login with azure (this part is ok). But after that, the app itself doesn't work, and the application is losing the connection. (I have this message in the top: "Connection lost, trying to reconnect...")

Apart from that a vaadin warning appears saying the following:

"Vaadin development mode initialized
[object Event]
Error in WebSocket connection to ws://localhost:35729/"

I don't know the origin of this localhost and how to avoid that issue.

To implement the login, I have followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory

I was checking if this issue has anything to do with LiveReload, but there is nothing related to it in my code.

I am working with Java17, spring-boo 2.7 and vaadin 23.3

I have not been able to find any relevant information about this localhost.

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve it?
Thanks in advance